# Python таблица умножения

Tags: python

на курсе изучения Python попалось задание составить таблицу умножения в таком виде:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я написал код, но не могу понять почему результат построения таблицы выводит не в таком формате, а немного смещенным вниз.

Вот сама задача:
Напишите программу, на вход которой даются четыре числа a, b, c и d, каждое в своей строке. Программа должна вывести фрагмент таблицы умножения для всех чисел отрезка [a; b] на все числа отрезка [c;d].

Числа a, b, c и d являются натуральными и не превосходят 10

Ссылка на компиляцию моего кода: https://onlinegdb.com/HJRtz2rgw

Comment: `print('\n',i,end='  ')` вместо `print('\n','\n',i,'\n',end='  ')`

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a, b, c, d = int(input()), int(input()), int(input()), int(input())
for k in range(c,d + 1): 
    print('\t',k,end='')
for i in range(a,b + 1):
    print('\n','\n',i,end='  ')
    for k in range (c,d + 1):
        print('\t',i * k,end='')
```

в 5й строчке у вас лишний перевод строки после i